How to request for a better seat in the institute in a good way
I joined to work in an institute.  This institute has three rented buildings, say A,B and C. Sometimes we have to move among them to complete tasks.
The washroom facilities of C are not that good but however I have been given my table in there. There are another 4 staff members in the same room with 4 tables for them.
Since the number of staff is lesser, its easy to concentrate so I didn't request to move to any other building.  But some others who had been sent there have requested to move and had moved to A, except the 4 members remaining with me (that's not an issue, I just mentioned the details).
In A and B, there are large halls with about 20 tables where a lot of staff sit together as well as a few smaller rooms with 2-3 tables too.
Now I will tell a bit about myself, please don't think I'm trying to boast I'm trying to speak about my qualifications, I'm just mentioning them hoping it'll be useful to tell me an answer.
I'm in a senior position according to my qualifications. But I'm young in age and so the junior members who are a majority sitting in the larger rooms, kind of try to Bulley me or over-ride me sometimes. I'm not very good in speaking to argue and I'm introverted evethough I'm qualified. And this staff has some internal politics and have attitudes and that's why they do like that.
Moreover,  I'm bit slow in typing in the computer but the errors are minimum in mine comparatively,  but I can't use that as an argument against them laughing at me if they observe my slowness.
I've been saved from major harassment according to the prevailing environment because I've been at C so far, but now the management has asked all staff to move to either A or B, perhaps they are hoping to remove C...
I'm glad if I can request to have a table in one of the few rooms with 2-3 tables. Some of the seniors as well as some juniors have been given such rooms, and a few people who had been sitting in such rooms have left recently too. I don't know whether some others also have requested for those seats. But they can allocate another new smaller room too if my request really gets in to their heart.
Therefore, can you please advise on how to make an impressive request without sounding biased (and also without mentioningabout others harassing me if possible)?
Thanks a lot in advance.

"I'm in a senior position according to my qualifications." Die that just mean you are in principle qualified or do you actually have a senior position?

Question: Which location is this in - as I have a sneaky suspicion that there are some cultural norms that will radically change what is and is not a good answer.

If you are slow at typing, you should take a course. So you get up to 120 characters per minute or 30 words per minute at least. And trained enough so no more than 1% of your brain power gets wasted on typing. This is not a joke, this is serious. Your typing speed is holding you back.

I'm actually in a senior position @MisterMiyagi

This is in an Asian country @TheDemonLord

Okay I will try that. But I need to stay out of harassment until then too @gnasher729

@BuddhiniAngelika - Asia is an entire continent. Malaysian cultural norms are not the same as Chinese norms or pakistan norms etc.

@TheDemonLord: She already uses her real name (most likely). That is already dangerous enough. Providing the country name, makes her easy to spot by her colleagues / bosses - if they hang around here too.

@BuddhiniAngelika: If that is your real name, you should change it quickly to something that cannot be used to identify you.

@virolino - Agree that using a real name is silly - however, since the question is one about corporate etiquette (fundamentally) then knowing about the culture of where they work is critically important. Asia is such a large continent with many distinct cultures. What would be perfectly acceptable in say Indian would be highly rude in Japan, despite both being considered Asia.

Thank you @virolino and

@TheDemonLord my name is very long and I'm not commonly using this part. But however I'm reluctant to reveal the exact country.

@TheDemonLord: I fully agree with you that the country is more important than the name - but now the name is already in the open. But if the real name is very long, then probably it is India :) In japan (occasionally they have long names) they would not negotiate much the decision of a manager to move to a certain place. But a clarification would help definitely.

@BuddhiniAngelika: We could help you better if you would provide the name of the country (as TheDemonLord mentioned, the cultural background can change the rules of the game greatly). And it would be better for you to change your user ID to something that cannot be traced back to you. E.g. ThePurpleDove, or Ronin707 or anything else that pleases you, but is not part of your identity. If Buddhini or Angelika are NOT part of your name, and you do NOT use them anywhere else, then they are fine.

Okay thank you very much @virolino Have a nice day! :)

Just explain what you don't like about your current location, and ask if it can be changed. If you can offer business reasons to change it, such as needing to be near another group to better collaborate with them, or the new location being better for meeting with customers, that's your best bet.
But expect to be disappointed. Somebody has to go into that office you don't like.

Okay thank you very much @keshlam I will try it. It's difficult to explain what I don't like since they might misunderstand though

If it's important enough to you, and legitimate, you will find a way to explain it. They still may disagree, of course.

Hmm okay @keshlam
